# select query on a table is hanging when a stored procedure to update the table is run

Tags: sql-server

I've a simple stored procedure to update a table as follows:

This sp is updating the table properly. But when I execute select query on po_tran table, its hanging.
Is there any mistake in the stored procedure..?

```sql
alter procedure po_tran_upd @locid char(3) 
as 

SET NOCOUNT ON;
begin
    update t 
    set t.lastndaysale = (select isnull(sum( qty)*-1, 0) 
                          from exp_tran 
                          where exp_tran.loc_id  =h.loc_id and 
                                item_code = t.item_code and 
                                exp_tran.doc_date > dateadd(dd,-30,getdate() ) 
                                and exp_tran.doc_type in ('PI', 'IN', 'SR')), 
    t.stk_qty = (select isnull(sum( qty), 0) 
                  from exp_tran 
                  where exp_tran.loc_id  =h.loc_id and 
                  item_code = t.item_code )
    from po_tran t, po_hd h 
    where t.entry_no=h.entry_no and 
          h.loc_id=@locid and 
          h.entry_date> getdate()-35
end

;
```

Comment: Hi ANAS, Please formate your sample code and your question properly, So I can understand your question and help you.

Comment: Why are you using a `CURSOR` here to process an `UPDATE` 1 agonising row at a time? SQL is a set based language, so you should be using set based methods. A `CURSOR` is one of the slowest operations you can implement in SQL Server.

Comment: I changed it as follows:

alter procedure po_tran_upd @locid char(3) 
as 

SET NOCOUNT ON;
begin
 update t set t.lastndaysale = (select isnull(sum( qty)*-1, 0) from exp_tran where exp_tran.loc_id  =h.loc_id and 
 item_code = t.item_code and exp_tran.doc_date > dateadd(dd,-30,getdate() ) and exp_tran.doc_type in ('PI', 'IN', 'SR')), 
 t.stk_qty = (select isnull(sum( qty), 0) from exp_tran where exp_tran.loc_id  =h.loc_id and item_code = t.item_code )
 from po_tran t, po_hd h where t.entry_no=h.entry_no and h.loc_id=@locid and h.entry_date> getdate()-35
end

;

Comment: Hi @Anas can you explain what you mean by its hanging.

Comment: It's probably hanging because going really slowly. Check your indexing

Answer (score 0):

Try the following possible ways to optimize your procedure.

1. Read this [article](https://www.codingvila.com/2019/01/cursor-in-sql-server-with-syntax-and-example.html), where I have explained the same example using [CURSOR](https://www.codingvila.com/2019/01/cursor-in-sql-server-with-syntax-and-example.html), Here I also have updated a field of the table using [CURSOR](https://www.codingvila.com/2019/01/cursor-in-sql-server-with-syntax-and-example.html).
2. **Important**: Remove Subquery, As I can see you have used a subquery to update the field.

- You can use Join or Save the result of your query in the temp variable and you can use that variable while update.

**i.g**

```
DECLARE @lastndaysale AS FLOAT
DECLARE @stk_qty AS INT

     select @lastndaysale = isnull(sum( qty)*-1, 0) from exp_tran where exp_tran.loc_id  =h.loc_id and 
    item_code = t.item_code and exp_tran.doc_date > dateadd(dd,-30,getdate() ) and exp_tran.doc_type in ('PI', 'IN', 'SR')

    select @stk_qty = isnull(sum( qty), 0) from exp_tran where exp_tran.loc_id  =h.loc_id and item_code = t.item_code

    update t set t.lastndaysale =@lastndaysale, 
    t.stk_qty = @stk_qty
    from po_tran t, po_hd h where t.entry_no=h.entry_no and h.loc_id=@locid and h.entry_date> getdate()-35
```

This is just a sample example you can do need full changes in that.

Comment: Your subquery will scan each row of the table one by one, so it may take longer to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I added a possibly more performant update, however, I do not fully understand your question. If "any" query is running slow against the po_tran, then I suggest you examine the indexing on that table and ensure it has a proper clustered index. If "this" query is running slow then I suggest you look into "covering indexes". The two fields entry_no and item_code seem like good candidates to include in a covering index.

```
update t 
set t.lastndaysale = 
    CASE WHEN  e.doc_date > dateadd(dd,-30,getdate() AND e.doc_type in ('PI', 'IN', 'SR') THEN 
        isnull(sum(qty) OVER (PARTITION BY  e.loc_id, t.item_code) *-1, 0)
    ELSE 0
    END,
t.stk_qty = isnull(SUM(qty) OVER (PARTITION BY e.loc_id, t.item_code),0)
from 
    po_tran t
    INNER JOIN po_hd h ON h.entry_no=t.entry_no AND h.entry_date> getdate()-35
    INNER JOIN exp_tran e ON e.loc_id = h.loc_id AND e.itesm_code = t.item_code
where 
      h.loc_id=@locid
```